# Pegar o valor abertoCaixa do Maior idCaixa

Tags: mysql

Essa é minha tabela, eu quero pegar o valor `abertoCaixa` do maior `idCaixa`.

```
  CREATE TABLE tblcaixa 
  ( 
     idcaixa            INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY auto_increment, 
     aberturacaixa      DOUBLE(200, 2), 
     abertocaixa        INT, 
     totalcaixa         DOUBLE (200, 2), 
     hrsaberturacaixa   DATETIME, 
     hrsfechamentocaixa DATETIME 
  );
```

Comment: Qual é a sua dúvida? O que você tentou até agora? Suponho que sua dúvida seja sobre MySQL e não sobre MySQL Workbench.

Comment: select max(idCaixa) from tblCaixa; esse código pega o maior idCaixa, porém eu quero pegar o valor abertoCaixa do maior idCaixa

Comment: Sugiro [edit] a pergunta e adicionar o máximo de informações possível

Answer (score 3):

A query abaixo pode ser uma possibilidade para retornar o que você precisa.

```
SELECT abertoCaixa FROM tblCaixa WHERE idCaixa = (SELECT MAX(idCaixa) FROM tblCaixa);
```

Comment: Exatamente isso! Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Não precisa de dois `SELECT` para isso, basta ordenar de forma decrescente pelo `idcaixa` e buscar o primeiro registro:

```
SELECT abertocaixa
FROM tblcaixa
ORDER BY idcaixa DESC
LIMIT 1
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/reuSvNtxgMrHUJetphK8mB/0)</sup>